# Flow: Convert object to array for CSV export

Tags: doctrine-orm, flow-framework

I want to export my object "mitglied" to a .csv-file. My controller looks like that:

```
public function exportAction() {

    // find all mitglieds
    $records = $this->mitgliedRepository->findTennis();

    // Set path for export-file
    $csvPath = '/var/www/apps/flow/Packages/Application/ITOOP.Atc/Resources/Private/Export/test.csv';

    $fp = fopen($csvPath, 'w');

    foreach ($records as $lines) {
        fputcsv($fp, $lines);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

When I call the exportAction, I get a an error:

> #1: Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given in /var/www/apps/flow/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/itoop_atc_Controller_MitgliedController.php line 494

line 494 is...

```
fputcsv($fp, $lines);
```

...so I think I have to convert the object "mitglied" to an array.

My the public function `findTennis` in my mitgliedRepository looks like that:

```
public function findTennis() {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $result = $query->matching($query->equals('abteilung', 'Tennis'))
                    ->setOrderings(array('name' => \TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING))
                    ->execute();

    return $result;
}
```

I tried to set toArray(); in the repository like the that:

```
public function findTennis() {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $result = $query->matching($query->equals('abteilung', 'Tennis'))
                    ->setOrderings(array('name' => \TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING))
                    ->execute()
                    ->toArray;
    return $result;
}
```

But then I get the following error:

> #1: Notice: Undefined property: TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\QueryResult::$toArray in /var/www/apps/flow/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/itoop_atc_Domain_Repository_MitgliedRepository.php line 105

line 105 of course is

```
 ->toArray;
```

Does anybody know, how to convert an object to an array in flow?

With the following example the export works, so I think the (formatting of the) repository query is the problem.

```
public function exportAction() {
    // Set path for export-file
     $csvPath = '/var/www/apps/flow/Packages/Application/ITOOP.Atc/Resources/Private/Export/test.csv';

 $test = array (
     array('xxx', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
     array('123', '456', '789'),
     array('aaa', 'bbb')
 );


 $fp = fopen($csvPath, 'w');

 foreach ($test as $lines) {
     fputcsv($fp, $lines);
 }

 fclose($fp);
```

}

Please point me to the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with arbitrary DQL. As I mentioned I think the problem was that I didn't got an array as result by the query. But with the following query in my repository I do:

```
/**
* @Flow\Inject
* @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
* inject Doctrine's EntityManager to execute arbitrary DQL
*/
protected $entityManager;    

/**
* find mitglieder with Abteilung Tennis und return an array
*/
public function exportTennis() {
    $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT mitglied FROM \itoop\atc\Domain\Model\Mitglied mitglied WHERE mitglied.abteilung = 'Tennis'");
    return $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

The important part I think is **getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);**

Answer (score 0):

#### The error messages explained

> #1: Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given in /var/www/apps/flow/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/itoop_atc_Controller_MitgliedController.php line 494

`fputcsv` expects it's 2nd parameter to be an array. That array will be written as a CSV line into single file, with each array element as column. When iterating over your `$records` variable, you get instances of your domain object class (so probably sth. like `ITOOP\Atc\Domain\Model\Mitglied`). That's undefined behaviour, thus the warning.

> #1: Notice: Undefined property: TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\Doctrine\QueryResult::$toArray in /var/www/apps/flow/Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/itoop_atc_Domain_Repository_MitgliedRepository.php line 105

`toArray` is a function that is offered by Doctrine `QueryResult` class. Typically, Doctrine queries do not fetch all objects returned by the query, but return an [iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) that fetches and maps entities on-demand. The `toArray` method fetches all records at once and returns an *array* instead of the iterator. Your error occurs, because you try to access `toArray` **as a property, and not calling it as a method**. The following code would be correct:

```
$result = $query->matching($query->equals('abteilung', 'Tennis'))
                ->setOrderings(array('name' => \TYPO3\Flow\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING))
                ->execute()
                ->toArray(); // <- Mind the brackets!
```

However, this will not help you anything, because in your controller, you will still be iterating over a list of domain entities (`foreach` does not care if its iterating over an iterator or an array; that's actually the point of iterators in PHP).

#### Quick&Dirty solution

Convert your domain entities by hand in your controller. **Only you can know how your CSV export should look like**, so this cannot be automated. I'm thinking something like this:

```
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $csvLine = [
        $record->getFirstProperty(),
        $record->getSecondProperty(),
        // and so on...
    ];
    fputcsv($fp, $csvLine);
}
```

#### Better solution

Rendering CSV data is **not a concern that should be addressed in the controller**. Basically, it should go into a view. You can implement **a custom view** class for handling the CSV output.

For that, you need to implement the `\TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\View\ViewInterface`. The easiest way to do this is to subclass `\TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\View\AbstractView`. Name your view class `<PackageNamespace>\View\<Controller>\Action<Format>` (so sth. like `ITOOP\Atc\View\Mitglied\ExportCsv`. Implement your CSV export logic in the view's `render()` method. Flow will pick up and use the view class automatically as soon as it's present.

Implementing custom views is explained in depth in [this article](https://networkteam.com/blog/verwendung-von-custom-views-in-flow.html) -- it's in German though, although based on your class naming I suspect that won't be a problem ;).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explaination. Intermediately I solved the problem with arbitrary DQL like explained in my following answer.